# Python: get name of a USB flash drive device [windows]

Tags: python, usb, wmi

I'm trying to write little program which will be able to read some informations about REMOVEABLE_DEVICE (USB). I've tried [pyusb](https://github.com/walac/pyusb) but I was not able to pull data I need.

I would like to read from the system the name of the USB device.

In this format:

```
USB Flash Memory - this is the model information
Removable Disk (H:) - this is the name of device

Generic Flash Disk
USB DISK (F:)

Lexar USB Flash Drive
Lexar (I:)
```

I am able to get the model information with **win32com.client** library, inspired from [here](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/python/0054/), but I am not able to get name of the device shown in Windows explorer.

Maybe I am using wrong library?

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = \"USB\"")
for objItem in colItems:
    if objItem.Caption != None:
        print "Caption:" + ` objItem.Caption[:-11]`
```

Here is link for Windows Win32_DiskDrive Class: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: I haven't really got any experience with the `win32com.client` library.

By starting with `Win32_DiskDrive` like you did, I went over [`Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394134(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175(v=vs.85).aspx), and then to [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the **`VolumeName`** which seems what you want.

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")

# 1. Win32_DiskDrive
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = \"USB\"")
DiskDrive_DeviceID = colItems[0].DeviceID.replace('\\', '').replace('.', '')
DiskDrive_Caption = colItems[0].Caption

print 'DiskDrive DeviceID:', DiskDrive_DeviceID

# 2. Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")
for objItem in colItems:
    if DiskDrive_DeviceID in str(objItem.Antecedent):
        DiskPartition_DeviceID = objItem.Dependent.split('=')[1].replace('"', '')

print 'DiskPartition DeviceID:', DiskPartition_DeviceID

# 3. Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
for objItem in colItems:
    if DiskPartition_DeviceID in str(objItem.Antecedent):
        LogicalDisk_DeviceID = objItem.Dependent.split('=')[1].replace('"', '')

print 'LogicalDisk DeviceID:', LogicalDisk_DeviceID

# 4. Win32_LogicalDisk
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID=\"" + LogicalDisk_DeviceID + "\"")
print 'LogicalDisk VolumeName:', colItems[0].VolumeName
print

# putting it together
print DiskDrive_Caption
print colItems[0].VolumeName, '(' + LogicalDisk_DeviceID + ')'
```

Works for me:

```
DiskDrive DeviceID: PHYSICALDRIVE1
DiskPartition DeviceID: Disk #1, Partition #0
LogicalDisk DeviceID: D:
LogicalDisk VolumeName: PENDRIVE

Sony Storage Media USB Device
PENDRIVE (D:)
```

This seems to provide a complicated, but possible way, maybe you can simplify it even more. My only simplification is leaving out [`Win32_DiskPartition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx) already because we only need the connection.

Please note:

- I'm not sure what's the "clean" way to unpack something like `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`, but it should be possible to get rid of the `.replace()`-methods.
- I'm not sure if it's possible to integrate the loops in steps 2 and 3 into the query? That would also simplify it a lot (maybe it's possible to `JOIN` them SQL-like?).
- (The code above will only work for a single USB drive.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your post. That is exactly what I was looking for! Great description of your steps I really appreciate that.

Comment: I adopted your code to allow returning multiple usb drives, if their name is not empty. I am sure both our pieces could be made better, but it works for me. Maybe somebody else can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

I will look odd but it will work (get list of all removable volume's `Label's`)

```
import os
os.system('echo list volume > Ravi.txt')
path1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Ravi.txt")
os.system('diskpart /s '+path1+' > logfile.txt')
path2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"logfile.txt")

Str = open(path2).read()
Str = Str.split('\n')
matching = [s for s in Str if "Removable" in s]

for i in matching:
    i = ' '.join(i.split())
    i = i.split(" ")
    print i[3]+"("+i[2]+":)"
```

**output**

```
MYPENDRIVE(D:)
```

Comment: Thank you for your submision. I would prefer solution using windows API. Anyway interesting idea, if I will not figure it out other way I will definitely use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the approach of @adrianus and improved a bit on it to return multiple usb drives. For how it works check his answer. For quick and dirty code that hopefully works for you check below :)

```
def get_usb_volume_name():  # pragma: no cover
    str_computer = "."
    logical_disk_device_ids = []
    volumes = []
    try:
        obj_wmi_service = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
        obj_swbem_services = obj_wmi_service.ConnectServer(str_computer, "root\cimv2")

    # 1. Win32_DiskDrive
    col_items = obj_swbem_services.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = \"USB\"")
    for item in col_items:
        disk_drive_device_ids = item.DeviceID.replace('\\', '').replace('.', '')

    # 2. Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
    col_items = obj_swbem_services.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")
    disk_partition_device_ids = []
    for obj_item in col_items:
        for disk_drive_device_id in disk_drive_device_ids:
            if disk_drive_device_id in str(obj_item.Antecedent):
                disk_partition_device_ids.append(obj_item.Dependent.split('=')[1].replace('"', ''))
                break

    # 3. Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
    col_items = obj_swbem_services.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
    for objItem in col_items:
        for disk_partition_device_id in disk_partition_device_ids:

            if disk_partition_device_id in str(objItem.Antecedent):
                logical_disk_device_ids.append(objItem.Dependent.split('=')[1].replace('"', ''))
                break

    # 4. Win32_LogicalDisk
    col_items = []
    for logical_disk_device_id in logical_disk_device_ids:
        col_items.append(obj_swbem_services.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID=\"" +
                                                      logical_disk_device_id + "\""))

    for col_item in col_items:
        volumes.append(col_item[0].VolumeName)
except IndexError:
    pass
volumes_result = []
logical_disk_device_ids_result = []
for i in range(len(volumes)):
    if volumes[i] != "":
        volumes_result.append(volumes[i])
        logical_disk_device_ids_result.append(logical_disk_device_ids[i])

return logical_disk_device_ids_result, volumes_result
```