# Trigger python script as soon as a specific USB device (Identified by product id and vendor id) is attached to the system

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, detection

I want to trigger a python script when a USB device which is identified by **product id** and **vendor id** is attached to the system. I'm working on windows 10 right now. but a cross platform solution is always welcomed.

Comment: Have you looked into `pywinusb` package?

Comment: @Raguel thanks seems like `pywinusb` has the potential

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to leave this as comment, but I'm not able to do that yet.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495206/how-to-detect-a-new-usb-device-is-connected-on-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857920/how-to-get-connected-usb-device-list-from-windows-by-using-python-or-cmd), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689090/detect-media-insertion-on-windows-in-python) it seems that you should be able to do what you want, have you tried any of these solutions?

In other words you should be able to:

1. Monitor ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495206/how-to-detect-a-new-usb-device-is-connected-on-python),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689090/detect-media-insertion-on-windows-in-python)) if any new device was connected by pooling
2. [Query the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python) for its infos and see if it is of your interest (on windows *WMI* seems the best option, but you can fallback to issue a powershell command for a quick and dirty PoC)
3. Perform the action if the condition are met

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Actually using `subprocess` to run a command is a hack not a solution (at least for me) and cause there is no dominating cross platform package in python (to my knowledge) such a question is asked every few years actually in Linux `pyudev` is a great solution

Comment: Nice, it seems that I can add comment to my own answer. I agree with you about the subprocess but sometimes this can be better than nothing. Have you also tried with [pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8110666/11265715)?

Comment: Yes, it 's on my radar but I think `pywinusb` suggested by @Raguel (%100 python) is better suited for this simple task